# do I need to use containerd on google cloud platform?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

3 months ago I can open jupyter notebook on google cloud with:

```
gcloud compute ssh gpu-1 --zone=asia-east1-b 
docker start tensorflow1 && docker exec -it tensorflow1 bash 
jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=8888 --allow-root
```

but now I can't. After careful examination，I found one sentence:

Ubuntu's Kubernetes 1.14 distributions can bypass Docker  and use containerd
directly

Is it this reason that I can't open jupyter notebook? should I use containerd with:

```
snap install microk8s --channel=1.14/beta —classic
```

or maybe other reasons that cause my problem

Comment: Can you install the docker package? Might be an easy avenue to return functionality.

Comment: If you use Ubuntu's Kubernetes, why not deploy your jupyter-notebook in Kubernetes's way ?

Comment: Maybe I can try next time,thanks

Answer (score 0):

After delete and rebuilt firewall，I was reborn